# Poisson distribution for large numbers

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Im trying to understand if a weekly number of certain metric (i e orders) has changed significantly during last week based on the performance of the previous 4 weeks.

I only take 4 weeks in the past to make sure seasonality is not big factor here + use Poisson distribution.

Let's say that mean (and lambda) of the previous 4 weeks is 5000 orders and the last week we got 4800 orders.

Then the probability of the number of orders being 4800 or lower is:

sum of ([image])
Here is my code to calculate it:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
rv = poisson(5000)
sum = 0
for num in range(0,4800):
    sum += rv.pmf(num)
print(sum)
    print(foo)
```

The result is 0.0021

Now, the common sense says its too small given it is just (4800-5000)/5000 = 4% down from the mean.

I suspect it is because 5000 is too big number for Poisson distribution - all the example i found were about smaller numbers.

Is this correct and how to work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your common sense says, in effect, "4%, no biggie, that's only $1/25$ of the total".  What your calculations are telling you is that a fluctuation of this size is pretty big, given the total volume of sales.

A Poisson distribution with expectation $5000$ is well-approximated by a normal distribution (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83283/normal-approximation-to-the-poisson-distribution) for example), and you are taking about a deviation of size $(4800-5000)/\sqrt{5000}\approx -2.8$ standard deviations.  One would expect such a deviation about one time in $400$ or so.

Details: you know the expectation of a $\text{Po}(\lambda)$  random variable is $\lambda$; you should also know that its variance is also $\lambda$.  So if $X\sim \text{Po}(\lambda)$ , the mean and variance of $Z=(X-\lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ are $0$ and $1$, respectively.  For other reasons $Z$  is approximately standard normally distributed, so your tail area is approximately $\Phi(-2.8)\approx .0023$, which is fairly close to what your exact calculation gave.

Whether this adds up to "significant" depends on what action you might take on this evidence.  Are you wondering if you want to ask the advertising  manager for a comment at the next sales meeting, or are you wondering if you want to sue your advertising firm?  I can't tell.  But the figure 4% is not what you should be concentrating on.

Comment: thanks @kimchi lover! would you recommend using normal distribution and say assume if it is less than -3 standard deviations away from the mean then the change is significant?

Comment: lover in your formula why is that divided by sqrt(mean)? Don't it have to be a standard deviation? can you please give some more details why we can replace standard deviation with sqrt(mean) in this case? Forgive me my newby question please..

Comment: @user912830823 I have edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: thanks a million! Are you referring to z-score in that formula =(−)/sqrt() ? If so i looked up online z-score formulas and found this: z = x – μ / σ. Now i understand why μ= but not sure why σ=sqrt()? This was a bit unclear in your answer, could you add some more details please?

Comment: I have added a reference in my 2nd paragraph.  Since _you_ brought up the Poisson distribution I thought you were acquainted with its basic properties.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!